# Password textbox value on jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a weird problem, i've been following a youtube tutrial from [Matt Blagden](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBVX14GkLb4&feature=related) in my quest to learn MVC3 .Net, everothing have been fine so far, but on his 4 video after the 13 min mark, he creates the following javascript :

```
function getPasswordHash(passwordElement, nonceElement, hashElement)
{
    var password = ('#' + passwordElement).attr('value');
    var nonce = ('#' + nonceElement).attr('value');

    $('#' + hashElement).attr('value', $sha256(password + nonce));
    $('#' + passwordElement).attr('value', '');
}
```

My javascript/jquery knowledge is really basic, but for me it makes sense, problem is, the java script won't execute, and the javascript console keeps giving me the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Object #password has no method 'attr'
getPasswordHashLogin.js:3
(anonymous function)Login:43
onclick"

This is my view code:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}
@section ExtraHeaders
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Login.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/SHA256.js")"></script>
}
<form action="@Href("~/Account/Login")" method="post" id="loginForm">
Name:
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<br />
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="@Model"  id="nonce" />
<input type="hidden" name="hash" value="hash" id="hash" />
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="getPasswordHash('password', 'nonce', 'hash'); $('#loginForm').submit();"
    value="Login" />
</form>
```

¿ What am i doing wrong ?, i cant tell what the problem is and its really pissing me off :@.

## EDIT

I changed the .js to the following:

```
function getPasswordHash(passwordElement, nonceElement, hashElement)
{
    var password = ('#' + passwordElement).attr('value');
    var nonce = ('#' + nonceElement).attr('value');

    $('#' + hashElement).attr('value', $sha256(password + nonce));
    $('#' + passwordElement).attr('value', '');
}
```

but the Javascript console give me the same error. i performed the forrowing test on the js console :

$('#password').text()
""
$('#password').val()
"123esda432"
$('#password').attr('value')
"123esda432"

Which shows that the password not only have a value, but have a attr() propierty, but as soon as i clicked the submit button i get the same error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #password has no method 'attr'
getPasswordHashLogin.js:3
(anonymous function)Login:45
onclick"

¿What is going on? @*_*@.

Comment: yeah, i have the follwing code set on my _Layout view:

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @RenderSection("ExtraHeaders", false);

</head>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `$` prefix.

```
var password = $('#' + passwordElement).attr('value');
var nonce = $('#' + nonceElement).attr('value');}
```

Also, you shouldn't need `attr('value');`

`.val()` should work just as well.

Comment: i cant believe i missed the $, i feel so dumb :$ .

But something weird happened after i fixed that, i keep guetting the same error :/.

Comment: @Q_ro, are you sure it is the exact same error on the exact same line? Or is it on a different line, a different variable, etc. I don't have the SHA256 script, but the rest of your code seems to be fine.

Comment: yes, the same error on the same line (line 3: This line "var password = ('#' + passwordElement).attr('value');") .

Comment: ok i fixed it, i was weird, but its a bug that have happen to me in the past, seems like the visual studio wasn't saving the changes to the .js, so even to i added the $ prefix, the .js at runtime seemed to be missing then, so i had to restart and add them again and now it works like a charm :), thanks, and sorry to bother with such a silly question :$.